# What happend to Ehcache distributed cache when one of the cache node dead?

Tags: ehcache, distributed-caching

I've read ehcache documentation and knows that all the data in distributed cache are distributed across all the nodes. That mean none of the node have all the cache data. So what happened when one of the node dead? The cache objects on that dead node are gone?

Answer (score 0):

Except if you use Terracotta as a clustering mechanism, all other ones would mean: all the data *only* present on the node that fails is lost.

Using Terracotta clustering, the data is "owned" by a Terracotta Server stripe, which can be backed up passive standby for HA. In such setups, data is *never* lost.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, and see what happend!

Answer (score 0):

Distibuted caching should technically entail that all data is distributed on all cache servers such that the memory is being pooled and at the same time it should be made highly available. This really means that you need a peer-to-peer architecture such that all servers act as peers and if one goes down there should be a replica of the data of this server on other servers in the cache cluster so that there is business continuity. One such product is NCache that provides a true peer-to-peer architecture.

http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/